# Nsarray with objects ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsarray

I have to create array like :

```
photos:[
      {
         "name":"20130201064350_01.jpg",
         "quantity":"2"
      },
      {
         "name":"20130201064350_02.jpg",
         "quantity":"1"
      }
   ]
```

Here, I have `name` array and `Quantity` array.

How can I create this type of array or dictionary?

Comment: Isn't that jSON notation system ? If yes should use SBJSon to parse this type of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is aarray of `NSMutableDictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic1 setValue:@"20130201064350_01.jpg" forKey:@"name"];
[dic1 setValue:@"2" forKey:@"quantity"];

NSMutableDictionary *dicn = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dicn setValue:@"n.jpg" forKey:@"name"];
[dicn setValue:@"n" forKey:@"quantity"];
```

// And to NSArray

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dic1, dic2, ........dicn, nil];
```

Comment: `setValue:forKey:` is not part of `NSDictionary`, but `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: @Martin- yup...u r right its my mistake.. thanks a lot for inform me :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the new syntax, this is simply:

```
NSArray *photos = @[
      @{
         @"name":@"20130201064350_01.jpg",
         @"quantity":@"2"
      },
      @{
         @"name":@"20130201064350_02.jpg",
         @"quantity":@"1"
      }
   ];
```

(i.e. pretty much just putting `@` in front of structure in your question).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = @[ @{ "name":"20130201064350_01.jpg", "quantity":"2" }, @{"name":"20130201064350_02.jpg", "quantity":"1"} ];
//These are new literals
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `Quantity` and `name` arrays are equal count. run a  for loop with any of one array and add it on `NSDictionary` and add that dicitonary into `NSMutableArray`.

ex:

```
 quantityArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:quantity1, quantity2, quantity3, ..., nil];

 namesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:name1, name2, name3, ..., nil];

 NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMUtableArray alloc] init];

 for (int i = 0; i < [namesArray count]; i++) {

 NSDictionary* dicitonary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:[namesArray objectAtIndex:i], [quantityArray objectAtIndex:i], nil];
   [mainArray addObject:dicitonary];
 }

 NSLog(@"mainArray = %@", mainArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check :

[NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html),

[NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

For example :

```
NSDictionary * d1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:@"20130201064350_01.jpg", @"name", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"quantity", nil];

NSArray * a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:d1, d2, d3, ..., nil];
```

Comment: your key and value of the dic is wrong order. It should be like this [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:@"20130201064350_01.jpg", @"name", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"quantity", nil];